# Playing Audio in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

What do you think is the best (i.e. most memory efficient) way of playing a few 30 second audio files (m4v) from the bundle within an app to the external speaker? The audio files have to play automatically as soon a specific view appears.

There is no mixing, etc. going on. However I'm listening to the microphone at the same time via `AVAudioRecorder` to measure a few noise levels/peak sounds etc. and react to them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m4v are video files. Did you mean m4p?

Assuming you did, I'd say start with [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Since you're using input at the same time as playback, you'll want to set your Audio Session's category appropriately:

```
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance].category = AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord;

// note that on the iPhone that category will send audio output to the 
// phone earpiece rather than the speaker, so you have to redirect the output
// like so:

UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;

AudioSessionSetProperty (
    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
    sizeof (audioRouteOverride),             
    &audioRouteOverride                      
);
```

Comment: They are actually m4a files. Thanks though, what you are suggesting sounds like a good idea!